# DataGrid elimina su contenido

Tags: c#

Quiero ir llenando diferentes columnas de un dataGrid, pero al agregar una nueva fila para poder seguir agregando mas contenido se borra lo que había en la anterior fila.

```
        public void Escribir (string xd,int columna)
    {
         if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
         {
            dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Escribir (xd,columna);
            }));
         }
        else
        {
            if(filaActualPorColumna[columna] +1>= dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }

            int f = filaActualPorColumna[columna];            
            dataGridView1.Rows[filaActualPorColumna[columna]].Cells[columna].Value=xd;
            filaActualPorColumna[columna] = f+1;
        }
    }
```

Por que ocurre esto?
Para solucionarlo use

```
                if(filaActualPorColumna[columna] +1>= dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }
```

Pero siempre deja una fila vacía al final

Comment: La fila vacia puede depender a como hayas definido la grilla.. si la definiste para que se puedan agregar filas por UI, entonces va a mostrar esa fila... despues, porque estas sobreescribiendo, y puede ser por multiples cosas, sobre todo, porque estes mirando mal la fila que queres usar...